# can't get nice table with kable / kableExtra with knitr2html

Tags: r, knitr, kableextra, kable

I'm using knit2html to generate html reports from R code.

Been trying to use kable / kableExtra to get table printed out nicely however doesn't seems to work.

I will use this simple program to demonstrate, all attempt to print out the table generate pretty crude print out rather than nice print out as I seen on some of the tutorial (e.g. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html)

R program:

```
#!/usr/bin/Rscript

library(data.table)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

test_data=data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     b=rep('a', 5),
                     c=rep(2.0, 5),
                     d=rep('a', 5),
                     e=rep(2.0, 5),
                     f=rep('a', 5),
                     g=rep(2.0, 5))

knit2html('test.Rmd')
```

Rmd file:

````
```{r testprint1, echo=FALSE}
test_data
```
```{r testprint2, echo=FALSE}
kable(test_data)
```
```{r testprint3, echo=FALSE}
test_data %>% kable("html")
```                  
```{r testprint4, echo=FALSE}
test_data %>% kable("html") %>% kable_styling()
```
````

A screen capture of result html:

[image]

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `rmarkdown::render()` instead of `knitr::knit2html()`. The latter should have been retired long time ago, and exists pretty much only for historical reasons. Specifically, `rmarkdown::render()` calls Pandoc to convert Markdown output, and `knitr::knit2html()` calls the **markdown** package. See [this article](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_migrating_from_v1.html) for more information.

Comment: Thanks Yihui that worked. Can you see my answer to the question (it was too long to be typed into comment). A question spawned out from this about how to control the output / intermediate files location of render()...

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark. If you have a new question, please just post a new question. Please don't keep asking under the same question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `knit2html` isn't bringing in bootstrap?

If you render from the markdown itself you get the nice table from `kable_styling`:

````
```{r echo=FALSE}
library(data.table)
library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)

test_data=data.table(a=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                     b=rep('a', 5),
                     c=rep(2.0, 5),
                     d=rep('a', 5),
                     e=rep(2.0, 5),
                     f=rep('a', 5),
                     g=rep(2.0, 5))
```

```{r testprint1, echo=FALSE}
test_data
```
```{r testprint2, echo=FALSE}
kable(test_data)
```
```{r testprint3, echo=FALSE}
test_data %>% kable("html")
```                  
```{r testprint4, echo=FALSE}
test_data %>% kable("html") %>% kable_styling()
```
````